# forming a new matrix depending on matrix of data and other matrix of indexs matlab

Tags: matlab

given matrix A of size 3 by 3 contain indexes, and outher matrix R of size 2 by 12 contain blocks of numbers, each block of size 2 by 2.
the perpse of the whole process is to form a new matrix contain the blocks within the R matrix depending on the order of the index within the matrix A.
and here is an exemple

matrix A:

```
A=[1 2 3;

   1 3 4;

   4 5 6]
```

matrix R:

```
R=[1 1 2 2  3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6;

   1 1 2 2  3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6 ]
```

the new matrix is:

```
New=[1 1 2 2 3 3; 

     1 1 2 2 3 3;

     1 1 3 3 4 4;

     1 1 3 3 4 4;

     4 4 5 5 6 6;

    4 4 5 5 6 6 ]
```

any ideas ?

Comment: The `R` in your example is 2x12, not 2x6: ?

Comment: yes !! in did. sorry!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your matrix `R` is defined as follows:

```
R = [1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6 ;
     1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6 ]
```

using your index matrix `A`

```
A = [ 1 2 3;
      1 3 4;
      4 5 6 ]
```

you need [**`mat2cell`**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html) and [**`cell2mat`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html) to achieve the desired output

```
%// clustersize in R
c = [2 2]

%// clustered R
Rx = mat2cell(R,c(1),repmat(c(2),size(R,2)/c(2),1));
%// or more direct
%// Rx = mat2cell(R,2,[2 2 2 2 2 2]);    

%// indexing of Rx with A and decollapsing of cell
out = cell2mat( Rx(A) )
```

---

```
out =

 1     1     2     2     3     3
 1     1     2     2     3     3
 1     1     3     3     4     4
 1     1     3     3     4     4
 4     4     5     5     6     6
 4     4     5     5     6     6
```

Comment: im soo sorry maybe the expetion that u used is not clear, well hope the edited syntex is more clear!

Comment: Okay i see, but i cant help you right now. I will edit my answer in a few hours

Comment: thats Awesome man!! i tried my code which contain 22lines, but you .... you did it in three lines! awesome man!!